# Cannot declare class App\Http\SeoInit\SeoInit, because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel, function, laravel-5, helper

I am creating a helper function its show this error

> Cannot declare class App\Http\SeoInit\SeoInit, because the name is
>   already in use.
>   Here is code

```
namespace App\Http\SeoInit;
class SeoInit
{
    public static function Funct_Name()
     {
         // 
      }

}
```

Thanks.

How to define a helper function into app.php aliases, The function is available in app->http Folder

Comment: please add some related code.

Comment: You already have a class with the same name in the same namespace. Try changing the name.

Comment: In aliases it is define like this: -> 'Seo' => App\Http\SeoInit\SeoInit::class,